# Injecting array of services

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-services

As far as I now, services need to be provided and injected, meaning each service has to be placed inside the constructor eg.:

```
constructor (private a: AService, private B: BService) {}
```

In my situation, I have a bunch of services (all implementing the same interface) I would like to hold in an array. How can I achieve this without a lot of redundancy (since I already have to state each twice for providing and injecting - right?)?
Regular classes instead of injectable services would not work for me because each of the services might need to use other services like HTTP which again have to be injected.

Comment: For your main question try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366108/angular-2-dynamic-dependency-injection-based-on-input/41367869#41367869

Comment: For `providers` - you can state your services in `@NgModule.providers` once and reuse it everywhere (just specify it in `constructor` like you did above), instead of repeating in every `@Component`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a simple helper array, let's call it "registry" and a dedicated array provider, we can make all registered instances available. Here a quick example:

```js
export class Examples extends Array<ExampleService> {}

const examplesRegistry = [ExampleServiceA, ExampleServiceB];

export function buildExampleProviders() {
  return [
    ...examplesRegistry,
    {
      provide: Examples,
      useFactory: (...args) => new Examples(...args),
      deps: examplesRegistry,
    },
  ];
}
```

As demonstrated below, we can still inject single instances (like `protected exampleA: ExampleServiceA`) or all of them with `protected examples: Examples`)

---

### full example + usage

```js
/// example.service.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export abstract class ExampleService {
  someProperty = Math.random();
  abstract name: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class ExampleServiceA extends ExampleService {
  override name = 'a';
}

@Injectable()
export class ExampleServiceB extends ExampleService {
  override name = 'b';
}
```

```js
/// examples.ts

export class Examples extends Array<ExampleService> {}

const examplesRegistry = [ExampleServiceA, ExampleServiceB];

export function buildExampleProviders() {
  return [
    ...examplesRegistry,
    {
      provide: Examples,
      useFactory: (...args) => new Examples(...args),
      deps: examplesRegistry,
    },
  ];
}
```

```js
/// app.component.ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleServiceA } from './example.service';
import { buildExampleProviders, Examples } from './examples';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [buildExampleProviders()],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    protected examples: Examples,
    protected exampleA: ExampleServiceA
  ) {}
}
```

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->
<pre>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let ex of examples; let i = index">
  examples[{{i}}]:
    .name: {{ ex.name }}
    .someProperty: {{ ex.someProperty }}
    .constructor.name: {{ ex.constructor.name }}
  </ng-container>

  exampleA:
    .name: {{ exampleA.name }}
    .someProperty: {{ exampleA.someProperty }}
    .constructor.name: {{ exampleA.constructor.name }}
</pre>
```

You can also try it out here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3kaagr?file=src/app/examples.ts