# Angular2, inject service on demand in a component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

This is my current component.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { SaleInvoiceService } from "../../services/sale-invoice.service";
import { SaleInvoice } from "../../modules/sales/sale-invoice/sale-invoice";

@Component({
  selector: 'fs-list',
  templateUrl: 'fs-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['fs-list.component.scss']
})
export class FSListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() config: any;

  data: SaleInvoice[];
  constructor(private service: SaleInvoiceService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAll()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.result.data = data;
      });
  }
}
```

I need to inject the service like customerService, SupplierService, SaleInvoiceService, etc. based on the service name mentioned in the fs-list component input value. Is there any way to inject service on demand, not initially in constructor

Comment: This looks like an XY question. What are you trying to achieve, at a higher level?

Comment: i have a component that fetches data and show the list. This component accept configuration which give details like serviceName, fields to show, etc. Based on the service name, i need to inject and fetch the data.

Comment: I wouldn't make this service take a service name as argument. I would make it take the data to display. Let the caller, which knows where to find the data (since it's supposed to pass the service) get the data and give them as input to your component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 dynamic dependency injection based on @Input()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366108/angular-2-dynamic-dependency-injection-based-on-input)

Comment: See this answer for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366251/3731501

Comment: thanks estus. It works