# Depends on the @Input change the providers useclass in Angular

Tags: angular

in the main module, imported `CalendarModule.forRoot({provide: DateAdapter, useFactory: adapterFActory})`

the calendar component, i received the @Input date: string, depends on the Input i want to change the Injector

First, i try make 2 injector and use if in providers useclass (but i don`t know how to get the input value in providers)

```
@Injectable()
export class MyCalendarUtils extends CalendarUtils {
  getMonthView(args: GetMonthViewArgs): MonthView {
    args.viewStart = subWeeks(startOfMonth(args.viewDate), 0);
    args.viewEnd = addWeeks(endOfMonth(args.viewDate), 1);
    return super.getMonthView(args);
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class EventsView extends CalendarUtils {
  getMonthView(args: GetMonthViewArgs): MonthView {
    console.log(args);
    const length = args.events.length;
    args.viewStart = subWeeks(startOfMonth(args.events[0].start), 0);
    args.viewEnd = addWeeks(endOfMonth(args.events[length - 1].start), -2);
    return super.getMonthView(args);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-match-calendar',
  templateUrl: './match-calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./match-calendar.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: CalendarUtils,
      useClass: (date == 'today') ? MyCalendarUtils : EventsView, //(ERROR)
    },
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useFactory: adapterFactory,
    }
  ],
})

export class MatchCalendarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() date; //today, events
}
```

Second i try if in injector but.. i don`t know how to get the Input value,

```
@Injectable()
export class MyCalendarUtils extends CalendarUtils {
  getMonthView(args: GetMonthViewArgs): MonthView {
    console.log(args);
    if (date == today) {    
        args.viewStart = subWeeks(startOfMonth(args.viewDate), 0);
        args.viewEnd = addWeeks(endOfMonth(args.viewDate), 1);
    } else {
        const length = args.events.length;
        args.viewStart = subWeeks(startOfMonth(args.events[0].start), 0);
        args.viewEnd = addWeeks(endOfMonth(args.events[length - 1].start), -2);
    }
    return super.getMonthView(args);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-match-calendar',
  templateUrl: './match-calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./match-calendar.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: CalendarUtils,
      useClass: MyCalendarUtils,
    },
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useFactory: adapterFactory,
    }
  ],
})

export class MatchCalendarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() date; //today, events
}
```

Any solution or another idea?  thank you

Comment: Inject both, then have a getter that calls the right service based on the input. 

    get calendarUtils(): CalendarUtils { return date == 'today' ? this.myCalendarUtils : this.eventsView; }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 dynamic dependency injection based on @Input()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366108/angular-2-dynamic-dependency-injection-based-on-input)

Comment: @BenL where to place the getter function code block and how (and where) to call it exactly?